# Raising to a non-integer Power for Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I am considering the following complex potential for a fluid flow

$w = U a \bigg(\frac{z}{a} \bigg)^{\pi/ \alpha}$.

I would like to obtain the velocity potential and stream function from this: one could do this by writing out $z = r e^{i \theta}$ and then expanding out the power.  However, what does one do in the situation that the power is not an integer, as now the power is a fraction of $\pi$, which is irrational.

Comment: A definition of a complex number raised to an arbitrary real power would be needed. (I don't know of such.)

Comment: I've thought about it and suspect they're not actually raising it to $\pi/ \alpha$. I think they raise it to the power $n$, expand the power and then you use a boundary condition on the stream function afterwards to conclude that $n= \pi/ \alpha$, which is not the same.

Comment: But then I'm puzzled because the components of the velocity are not the same when you differentiate the stream function and when you differentiate the velocity potential, should they not be the same?

Comment: Tom-- Can you change your question to what it should be? As it is now looks like complex to arbitrary real.